# WPF Control that renders a 2d dimension?

Tags: wpf, graphics, wpf-controls, vector-graphics

I need to render the value of the width or height of a 2d geometry object and the request is for it to not just be text, but somewhat like a dimension that would be a set of building plans. Something like <strike>this image</strike>...*oops too new to post images*...like this image that I googled -

http://www.archidigm.com/lounge/archdim/centerline_dim_1.gif

I have looked for something like this, but haven't been lucky in my search. I am fine with creating it, but thought that I would try to not reinvent the wheel if possible. Anyone know of a control or library out there that renders something like this?

Comment: here is another good example of the dimension objects I am looking to replicate. In this image it is everything in red - http://www.we-r-here.com/cad/tutorials/level_4/images/dim_sample_1.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article looks really helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613591.aspx. Although it talks about optimizing drawing, it gives mention to a lot of different classes you can use.

Specifically, take a look at the Drawing class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawing.aspx#snippetGroup1

If you want the shapes to be interactive (because it seems like you are building a CAD-like application), the `DrawingGroup` might help. Check out this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawinggroup.aspx#snippetGroup

Also, `DrawingGroup` might be a good way to group the actual shape (for example, a wall in a building) and the ruler object that shows the dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the links. The drawing objects aren't the problem, but rather it is showing the dimensions around the objects. Ruler is one option...but doesn't work well...the user wants to see it like the image link I provided. I think my search continues. Thanks though!

Comment: I see what you mean. I think that you will have to create your own class that can do this; shouldn't be too hard, I would think.

Comment: thanks for the words of encouragement. It sounds like a pretty good opportunity for an open source project...

Comment: I agree, It's an excellent candidate for open sourcing. Good luck!